# Empty shopping cart button not working

Tags: shopping-cart, magento2.4.4

I'm not sure what I have done to mess up the empty cart button in the shopping-cart page. Nothing happens, not even a page-refresh.

Its a multishop and it dosnt work on any shop. Not even using default luma shop.

I got it to work once in chrome Inkognito mode just before. It pupped the warning popup and cleared the cart fine. Afterwords it didnt work in Inkognito mode even.

What to look for or how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured myself after a while.

A mix the module ox/ajax-qty-update that needs to be updated after update to M2.4.x

Together with enabling this new configuration: Sales>Checkout>Enable Clear Shopping Cart

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you edited the class of the Clear Shopping Cart button, its class contains `action clear`.

The file contains the Clear Shopping Cart button is `<your custom theme dir>/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml`

Comment: The button seams okay
<button type="button" name="update_cart_action" data-cart-empty="" value="empty_cart" class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button">

Comment: Did you edit any files related to vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/shopping-cart.js or vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml?

Comment: Well no - and its the same for a untouched shop with luma theme. I just noticed something though. If I press the button, before all page/script loads or before the "order summary section" loads, it works?